# error: The function 'MyApp' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [i_am_a_rich_man] test\widget_test.dart:16)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() { 
    runApp(MaterialApp(home: Text('Snap''Kids')));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Update your method under main() method like this-
    
    void main() {
    runApp(MyApp(home: Text('Snap''Kids')));
    }
    
    OR 
    
    Goto widget_test.dart under test directory, and update
    
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    to
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp());

 Give correct sign if you find it working.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a folder called `test` in your root directory. When you create a new app, it will automatically create a test in `widget_test.dart` for `MyApp`. Since you have removed `MyApp`, you should probably just the delete the file in `test/widget_test.dart`.